# replace line with sed in csh

Tags: sed, foreach, line, csh

I am trying to change the content of a specific line in a batch of files. I thought that would be a piece of cake but for some reason, nothing happens, so I guess I am missing something.
Line 8 should have been replaced.

Here the csh script I used:

```
#!/bin/csh
#
# replace context in line xxx by yyy
# 2010/05/07

set files = `ls FILENAMEPART*`
echo $files
foreach file  ($files)
        sed  '8,8 s/1/2 /' $file 
end
```

thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed prints the resulting file (with the lines replaced) to stdout by default and leaves the source (input) file untouched. Use the -i option for in-place editing, which means that the changes are made directly in $file.

Comment: sure, i was just waiting for the minutes to pass before I was allowed to